# Aesthetics, cosmetics and psychology - on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

This question is linked to [We need to change our attitude towards new users!](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/915) as this is also about a question from a first time poster.

Ok, let's start with the second half of a comment left on [Can the slimming shirt help shape the skin so as not to saggy when the process of weight loss is happening?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/16435) which has votes for closure

> [After personal medical advice parts of the question is removed]....[w]hat's left then is "benefits", which is ill defined at best and in this case about aesthetics, cosmetics and psychology. Can you find an angle to make the "benefits" more clearly about health and medicine?

Can the following please be confirmed?:

- Health.SE discusses mental health?
- Ok, there is a Psychology.SE site, but Psychology is on topic here too?

These go hand in hand, and therefore,

- Is cosmetic/aesthetic improvements on-topic when they help with mental health?

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion, there is no doubt that the question is off-topic. So you’re asking if cosmetic improvements related to mental health are on topic in general?

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma - that's the basis of my query as the way I read the comment it seems to suggest it would not be.  I can understand the personal medical advice bit, bit cannot understand the aesthetics/cosmetics/psychology bit

Comment: I think they are strongly connected, see my answer below. I‘ll might be more elaborate tomorrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is cosmetic/aesthetic improvements on-topic when they help with mental health?

### No.

Cosmetics with no medical use should not be part of Health.SE. If the cosmetics alleviate a mental problem, the cosmetics are at least connected to health, but (a) would any such questions be personal and thus off-topic and (b) would we not be able to help with the cosmetic aspect of the question, thus rendering the whole QA process useless.

<sup>And yes, I think that Psychology should be migrated to Psychology.SE</sup>

Comment: Thanks.  I look forward to any elaboration as (b) is causing confusion. Ok, a slimming shirt may not physically help with sagging skin as such, but depending on the amount of sagging, the shirt may help with aesthetics which can help with any self-esteem issues.

Comment: @Chris Yes, but then we are not experts regarding slimming shirts (obviously). So although the question is connected to the mental health problem, the core question itself is about something we can't help with...

Comment: Ok.  I see where the line is now.