# Yet again, we have personal advice questions answered

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation, allowed-questions, answers

I am concerned that we are **still** having personal advice questions answered by those who have been here a long time and therefore should know that these questions **must never** be answered, and they should know by now the reasons why.

I think we need to come up with a solution to this before someone gets seriously harmed by following advice given in good faith and with good intentions.  What are the thoughts in the group?

Comment: 1. How to *encourage* users to visit & read & participate on meta? – Comment every problem answer with a link to here? – You may have to call out specific posts to illustrate the problem better. (There has been a real spree of "activity" that will surely cloud any easy identification, at least for me.)

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen this happening much, are there examples you had in mind?

Answer (score 2):

### Be Careful

I've talked about this before: [We need to be nicer](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/8212). And it is important to understand that a question is not off-topic until it has been closed as off-topic. Questions for personal advice aren't questions for personal advice until we have closed them. I find it difficult to punish unexperienced, new users with harsh downvotes because they allegedly answered something one personally deems off-topic. Heck, there are even questions where [the community itself is divided](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/16659/8212).

So keep in mind that other users might think differently about questions that are off-topic.

### Don't answer what you personally consider off-topic, but don't punish other users until the Community has decided where the question actually is off-topic.